# No Guide Spawned

Tags: terraria

I was playing the Terraria 1.3.5 update on PC, and I made a new world, but the NPC Guide did not appear in the game. **Does anyone know why this happened**? He is supposed to be there automatically when you make a new world.

Comment: Is this world with a new character, or an existing one?

Comment: a brand new world

Comment: with a new character?

Comment: yes a new character and world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you can try to do to spawn the guide back in but first

- Check your map and in any caves around spawn. There is a good chance that he fell down into a cave.

if you can't find him on your map then it must have been a bug causing him not to spawn in. Try to

- Build some houses. If the guide isn't spawned then he should be able to spawn back in if he has somewhere to live. If he moves in then restart the game. This will teleport him into his new house.
- Throw a [Guide Voodoo Doll](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide_Voodoo_Doll) into lava in hell. If the guide is alive somewhere this will kill him and spawn the wall of flesh. This will make sure he can spawn into a house.

If none of that works you'll just have to make a new world. If the glitch persists in all of your worlds I'd try to delete and reinstall the game.